# how to get VS2013 c++ compiler to use with Qt without installing VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

I've been out of it for awhile...I know I used to be able to get the msvc 2008 c++ compiler by installing a Windows SDK, and that worked fine for building with Qt Creator.

Is there a recommended way to get the msvc 2013 c++ compiler that will work with Qt, or do I have to install Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290501/can-i-download-the-visual-c-command-line-compiler-without-visual-studio), you can't.

Comment: @LogicStuff - thanks, that answers my question.  Not sure why that didn't come up for me when I searched SO.  Anyway, if you want to put your response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The answer is trivial, I've tried :).