# Compiling C++ with different Visual Studio versions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[Re. suggested link to other topic that might answer my question. That link answers the question, can I get the c++ compiler seperately from visual studio. That is somewhat related to my question (2). But it doesn't answer the more-important question (1).]

Retired professional software dev here.

I've come across a win32 GUI program described as "written in C++ and intendeded to be built with Visual Studio 2013".

I have no experience with C++, or modern tools like Visual Studio. But the sourcecode looks simple, and I'd like to add some features to it. This would be a good learning exercise, with a practical benefit.

The problem is, I don't want to install some massive IDE on my puny Windows 7 Starter atom netbook! So I'm after the very simplest environment that might compile and link this program. I don't even need an IDE, I'm happy to edit the sourcecode directly with Notepad!

At present I can't see any compatible-sounding VS product simpler than "Visual Studio Express For Desktop". So my questions are:

**(1)** Is it likely that Visual Studio Express For Desktop could compile and link a win32 C++ GUI application meant to be built with Visual Studio 2013? (or is that just a non-starter?)

**(2)** Is there a simpler solution (eg. a standalone compiler and linker) that might work?

In conclusion, I really do not want a full-on, bells-and-whistles environment. I want the very simplest environment that will let me just hack on this sourcecode.

I know that any solution will be slow on an atom netbook.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I download the Visual C++ Command Line Compiler without Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290501/can-i-download-the-visual-c-command-line-compiler-without-visual-studio)

Comment: I do not believe the compiler is distributed separately any more. If you can find Windows SDK 7, I think it's in there. You can also install a Visual Studio express edition and not use the IDE. The IDE will sit there like a dead weight on your hard disk but suck up few additional resources. Alternatives: See if the code will compile with [mingw (couple different flavours out there. Just linking one)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) and instead of notepad, [give Bowpad a look.](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/BowPad.html)

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio Express for Desktop 2013 has the full compiler. It can build whatever source code you have for Visual C++ 2013, unless that source code uses MFC or ATL libraries, which are not part of the Express edition (at that time they were commercial only). In order to use a free version of MFC, if that's necessary, you can install Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, but that's a huge beast.

Comment: In the other direction, more light-weight tools, if the source code is simple enough you may be able to build it with MinGW g++.

Comment: Express versions will work if you the win32 C++ GUI does not use MFC.  You could force it to use WTL: need to do some install script modifications.

Comment: Can you link to the project in question? a GUI application `"written in C++ and intendeded to be built with Visual Studio 2013"` could mean a lot of things, from MFC to C++/CLI (.NET) to Qt. If it's an open source project, it should be relatively simple enough for those familiar with those tools to browse and give more concrete answers .. ?

Comment: @user4581301 `I do not believe the compiler is distributed separately any more` That may no longer be true, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any luck, clean C++ code targeted at VC++ 2013 that's using the Win32 API directly (no MFC etc) should build with the [Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 Technical Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49983) (just the toolchain, no IDE). From the download page:

> This is a pre-release for Visual C++ Build Tools 2015. Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 provides the essential tools for building C++ applications and libraries targeting Windows desktop. If you want to build your C++ projects targeting Windows desktop without having Visual Studio installed on your computer, Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 provides the requisite C++ compilers, libraries, build scripts, and Windows SDKs.
>
> PLEASE NOTE: This Technical Preview has not been subject to final validation and is not meant to be run on production workstations or servers.
>
> The Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 Technical Preview ships with the same C++ compilers and libraries packaged with the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Comment: Thanks to all for the excellent comments (all of which I have read carefully), and answer. I've marked the VC++ Build Tools 2015 reply as the answer, since that seems to be just what I want. I'll return in due course and say if it worked.